# Android Bundling failed error In my react native App

Tags: android, react-native, symlink, simulator, expo-go

[image: 1]

Why Expo go app not working. But in my browser it works.

Comment: you use vector-icon plugin ?

Comment: no I used  "npm install @expo/vector-icons"

Comment: you need to read doc and link it proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again I create with "npm init" and again did same process .This time no errors .I used Expo App from started instead of Web as a emulator. The reason for this problem is in web Emulator not showing some errors
related to the real emulators.